# After publishing my unity game to Google Play and installing from the store, there is no Open/Play button

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, publishing

The game is listed on Google Play, but when I install it there is only an uninstall button. Also, the game icon is not added to the device. I've tried with multiple devices.

In `settings -> apps`, I can find the game, but no option to launch it.

This is my first game and I'm very excited, so will appreciate any help !!

The game:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ijgames.morf

Comment: please share assets/plugins/android/AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.google.unity.ads" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
  <application>
    <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-6148490449331637~7579554346" />
  </application>
</manifest>

Answer (score 1):

Actually the main reason was that I haven't built apk for last version and was building aab, which was not showing errors. So I fixed the errors for apk build and all good.

Comment: Haven't checked, I've left your version :) But both were giving an error of manifest merging. Have fixed that and everything works. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the UnityPlayerActivity to your manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.google.unity.ads" android:versionName="1.0" 
android:versionCode="1"> 
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" /> 
<application> 
<uses-library android:required="false" android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" /> 
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-6148490449331637~7579554346" /> 
  <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:taskAffinity="">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter> 
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
     </activity>
</application> 
</manifest>
```